# Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 vs 1.0

Tags: asp.net, accessibility

I have just realised that version 2.0 of the guidlines are available.

Having just made my website compliant to 1.0 of the guidlines recently I'm wondering what the differences are between 1.0 and the new version of the guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/from10/diff.php

and

http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/from10/comparison/